# Unable to Clear ComboBox Value when opening workbook

Tags: vba, combobox, initialization

When I open my workbook there are several things I want to do. One of those is to clear all the values from my Activex controls. Below is my code

```
 Public Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = Application.Workbooks("Incident_Form v11")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Error Form")

ws.Range("D5").Value = "F&C-3000" &     (Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 1000000000))

ws.ComboBox2.Value = Null
ws.ComboBox3.Value = Null
ws.ComboBox4.Value = Null
ws.ComboBox5.Value = Null
ws.ComboBox6.Value = Null
ws.ComboBox7.Value = Null
ws.ComboBox8.Value = Null
ws.ComboBox9.Value = Null
ws.ComboBox10.Value = Null
ws.ComboBox11.Value = Null
ws.ComboBox12.Value = Null
ws.ComboBox13.Value = Null
ws.ComboBox14.Value = Null
ws.ComboBox15.Value = Null
ws.ComboBox16.Value = Null
ws.ComboBox18.Value = Null

End Sub
```

For some reason when it gets to ws.ComboBox8 it spits our an error saying 'Object doesn't support this method or property'. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

`ws.ComboBox8` can not be the same as the others, delete it, copy and paste `ws.ComboBox7`, and rename it to `ComboBox8`.